# How to store the result of a stdout?

Tags: javascript, string, unix, meteor, client-server

I do a UNIX command to list all my files that ends with `.svg` like this

```
'getExistingFiles': function () {  
 var list ="";  
 child = exec_tool('cd /home/me/files/; ls *.svg',
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            list = stdout;
            console.log(typeof list);
            console.log("LIST:------------");
            console.log(list);
            return list;
            if (error !== null) {
                 console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                 list = "error: " + error;
                 return list;
            }else{
              console.log("Listing done");
            }
          });  
}
```

I have a result:

```
string
LIST:------------
test.svg
output.svg  
test2.svg
```

then with JavaScript I want to create a new element for each file that is in the `list` but I can't return my `list` I always got "undefined"

[image]

So what is wrong with my `list` ?  Why I can't access it from the client despite it's a string ? I think the error is on the server so could you help me to find it ?

Comment: Show the source code of getExistingFiles-method, pls.

Comment: @iiro it's the code on the post (the first code block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you. Async function using fiber/future. Let's tweak this in case you run into issues.

**Server.js**

```
  // 
  // Load future from fibers
  var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");
  // Load exec
  var exec = Npm.require("child_process").exec;

  Meteor.methods({
    runListCommand: function () {
      // This method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
      // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
      // to queue other method calls (see Meteor docs)
      this.unblock();
      var future=new Future();
      var command="cd /home/me/files/; ls *.svg";
      exec(command,function(error,stdout,stderr){
        if(error){
          console.log(error);
          throw new Meteor.Error(500,command+" failed");
        }
        future.return(stdout.toString());
      });
      return future.wait();
    }
  });
```

**Client.js:**

```
  Meteor.call('runListCommand', function (err, response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: it would works too, I tested it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It's because exec_tool is a async  function?

Try [wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync), somethign like this. See more from [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync).

```
'getExistingFiles': function () {  
 var list ="";  
 var et = Meteor.wrapAsync(exec_tool);

 try {
  child = et('cd /home/me/files/; ls *.svg');
  return child.stdout;
 } catch (err) {
  throw new Meteor.Error(err, err.stack);
 }   
}
```

Comment: I still got `undefined` on the client

Comment: Why you did same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110441/how-to-return-a-sdtout-from-a-server-to-a-client-inside-a-string

Comment: I wanted to make a new one clearer than this one

Comment: Ok, and fill SO with similar questions. IMO you should edit this one.

Comment: ok I'll know for next time ! Thank you for the advice I'll put the flag duplicate