# How to return a sdtout from a server to a client inside a string?

Tags: javascript, string, meteor, promise, client-server

I'm trying to return the `stdout` of my method but on the client I always have `undefined` despite the server says it's a `string` with content.

I do that:

```
'getExistingFiles': function () {
      var list = "";
      return new Promise(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(resolve) {
        child = exec_tool("ls -al",
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error !== null) {
              console.error('exec error: ' + error);
              list = "error: " + error;
              resolve(list);
              return list;
            }else{
              list = stdout;
              console.log(typeof list);
              console.log("LIST:------------");
              console.log(list);
              resolve(list);
              return list;
            }
          });
      }));
}
```

On my terminal I have the logs:
[image]

But on the client when I try to access the value it's `undefined`:

```
Meteor.call("getExistingFiles",function(list){
       console.log(list);
       console.log(typeof list);
});
```

So my question is, how could I send this `list` to the client ?

[EDIT] I tried like this to test if it was my client who was wrong but no it's on the server I think

```
//server      
var et = Meteor.wrapAsync(exec_tool);
 try {
  child = et('ls -al');
  console.log("LIST:------------");
  console.log(child);
  console.log(typeof child);
  return child;
 } catch (err) {
  throw new Meteor.Error(err, err.stack);
}
```

[EDIT2] even like this it send a `undefined` WHY ?!

```
var et = Meteor.wrapAsync(exec_tool);
      try {
       var proc = exec_tool("ls -al")
       proc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
         //do something with data
         console.log(data);
         list = list + data;
       });
       proc.stdout.on('end', function() {
         console.log("end");
         console.log(list);
         return list;
       });
      } catch (err) {
       throw new Meteor.Error(err, err.stack);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server (promises from the server are evaluated and then sent to the client when they're done):

```
getExistingFiles: function () {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child = exec_tool("ls -al",
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
              reject(error);
            } else {
              resolve(stdout);
            }
          });
      }));
}
```

And on the client:

```
Meteor.call("getExistingFiles", function(err, list) {
    if(err) {
        // handle your error
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(list);
});
```

Promises don't have `return`. Callbacks from async functions usually have the `function (error, result)` argument list. So, the wanted result should be in the second argument. Try it like this.

Comment: could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156414/how-to-send-the-stderr-full-text-to-the-client-with-a-promise since I use your method in an other use case and I can't get the error content

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a dupe question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108142/how-to-store-the-result-of-a-stdout)

See if this works for you. Async function using fiber/future. Let's tweak this in case you run into issues.

**Server.js**

```
  // 
  // Load future from fibers
  var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");
  // Load exec
  var exec = Npm.require("child_process").exec;

  Meteor.methods({
    runListCommand: function () {
      // This method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
      // asynchronous code to finish, so we call unblock to allow this client
      // to queue other method calls (see Meteor docs)
      this.unblock();
      var future=new Future();
      var command="cd /home/me/files/; ls *.svg";
      exec(command,function(error,stdout,stderr){
        if(error){
          console.log(error);
          throw new Meteor.Error(500,command+" failed");
        }
        future.return(stdout.toString());
      });
      return future.wait();
    }
  });
```

**Client.js:**

```
  Meteor.call('runListCommand', function (err, response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```